# getting multiple checkboxes names/id's with php

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

How can i get the names or id's of the multiple selected checkboxes on submit, using the PHP? Following is example form. Thanks.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="orange" id="orange">
   <input type="checkbox" name="apple" id="apple">
   <input type="checkbox" name="sky" id="sky">
   <input type="checkbox" name="sea" id="sea">
   <br>
   <br>
   <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Checkbox values are submitted from a form only if the checkbox is selected. What's more, it's the name attribute that counts, not the ID.

There are several ways of handling checkboxes in PHP:

1. Give all checkboxes the same name followed by a pair of square brackets, so the entire set is treated as an array. In this case, give each checkbox a value.
2. Give each checkbox a different name and a value.
3. Give each checkbox a different name, but no value.

In each case, you need to check for the existence of the checkbox name in the $_POST array.

For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" id="orange" value="orange">
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" id="apple" value="apple">
```

To get the values for these checkboxes:

```
if (isset($_POST['color'])) {
    $colors = $_POST['color'];
    // $colors is an array of selected values
}
```

However, if each checkbox has a different name and an explicit value like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="orange" id="orange" value="orange">
<input type="checkbox" name="apple" id="apple" value="apple">
```

You still need to use isset():

```
if (isset($_POST['orange'])) {
    // orange has been set and its value is "orange"
}
```

If you don't set a value, the default value is "on", but it won't be in the $_POST array unless it has been selected, so you still need to use isset().

Answer (score 10):

You need to give the inputs the same name:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="orange">
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="apple">
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="sky">
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="sea">
```

Then iterate over the $_POST['selection'] array in PHP.

Comment: If you simply name them the same, this will not work. You need to set them up as arrays: `name="selection[index]"`

Comment: fixed the example. Also I think you can leave out the index and they will automatically be indexed.

Comment: Yes you could do that as well, he did specifically ask to preserve the "name" attribute though. The index could substitute that.

Answer (score 4):

You won't get the ids but the names will be associative indexes in the `$_POST` array (and `$_REQUEST`). NOTE: They will only be available in the array if they were checked by the client.

`if ($_POST['oragne'] == 'on')`

Answer (score 2):

You can set them up to post to PHP as arrays, if you build them similar to below:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="box_group_1[oragne]" id="oragne">
   <input type="checkbox" name="box_group_1[apple]" id="apple">
   <input type="checkbox" name="box_group_1[sky]" id="sky">
   <input type="checkbox" name="box_group_1[sea]" id="sea">
   <br>
   <br>
   <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
print_r($_POST['box_group_1']);
?>
```