# Javascript check all checkboxes with same ID

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have the following

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="pic-container">

                    <label>
                        <span><input type="checkbox" name="discounting" onchange='handleChange(this);' id='check11' value="">ciao</span><br>
                    </label>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="pic-container">

                    <label>
                        <span><input type="checkbox" name="discounting" onchange='handleChange(this);' id='check21' value="">hola</span><br>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span><input type="checkbox" name="discounting" onchange='handleChange(this);' id='check21' value="">hola</span><br>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span><input type="checkbox" name="discounting" onchange='handleChange(this);' id='check21' value="">hola</span><br>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span><input type="checkbox" name="discounting" onchange='handleChange(this);' id='check21' value="">hola</span><br>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span><input type="checkbox" name="discounting" onchange='handleChange(this);' id='check21' value="">hola</span><br>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span><input type="checkbox" name="discounting" onchange='handleChange(this);' id='check21' value="">hola</span><br>
                    </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Id like by clicking the first check box that all check boxes in the second div with an ID of "check21" to be chacked automatically.

```
<script>
    function handleChange(cb) {
        if(cb.checked == true) {
           document.getElementById("check21").checked = true;
           alert('eyaicecold');
        } else {
           alert('Message 2');
           var x = document.getElementById("check21").disabled= false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have used the following script which works but only for the first one. I wan to use the ids since the name and the value will be used to send the sql request  trough the form.

Comment: It is not valid HTML to have multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: @Patrick2607 Or names. Which, ironically, OP is already doing.

Comment: @Siguza He's using multiple instances of the same ID in his DOM, that's not valid HTML and will cause conflicts, I wasn't answering his question but suggesting he should use classes if he wants to initiate multiple instances with the same selector.

Comment: `var test = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"])');`

Comment: a id must be uniqe in html, you should use classes

Comment: @Patrick2607 No need to teach me basic HTML, I was just saying that names are about as good as classes in this case, especially since all his checkboxes already have `name="discounting"` set.

Comment: @Siguza true - but in this case not all of those `name=discounting` items have the same id-that-should-be-a-class, so you'd match the wrong set of checkboxes.

Comment: @PaulRoub You're right, I missed the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, IDs **must** be unique, so you can change them to classes if you like. Then you can use this jQuery:

```
$('input.check11').click(function(){
  $('input.check21').prop('checked',this.checked)
})
```

**[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/RbhXz6tXi5)**

Also, remove those inline event handlers.

Answer (score 2):

As said before, each element on a webpage should have a unique ID.

However, it can still be done using *querySelectorAll* like so:

```
function handleChange(cb) {
    var allCB = document.querySelectorAll("input[id='check21']");
    for(var i=0; i< allCB.length; i++){
        allCB[i].checked=true;
    }
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/kg9jkhnk/)

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind IDs is that they are unique. It's what allows you to get a single element with the `getElementById` function, while other `getElementsByXXX` functions return a list of elements (hence the s in getElement**s**).

When you retrieve the POST data (through PHP or another server language), you will need to check if the variable called like the name attribute is set. If it is, then the checkbox was checked. Having multiple checkboxes with the same name like you did won't work. [This other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4631595/2813263) explains how to use POST data from checkboxes very well.

If you choose to go with `name="something[]"` notation, when you could check all boxes of the second div with:

```
var checkboxes = myDiv.getElementsByName("something[]");
for(var i=0; i < checkboxes.length; ++i) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = true;
}
```

You could also use classes, but I think that would just bloat the code while you already need to use names for forms anyway.

Comment: I am not sure about latest version(s) of IE, but earlier versions do not support getElementsByName()

Comment: @dneimeier Not sure where you're taking that from, getElementsByName has existed since the [early drafts of DOM 2 back in 1999](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-DOM-Level-2-19990923/) so I'm pretty sure any browser that wouldn't support it wouldn't be compatible with any site made today.