# Bootstrap form group checkboxes doesn't get checked in between nav pills

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's the JSFiddle of my work: https://jsfiddle.net/pb23Ljd8/5/

I use Bootstrap nav-pills to show all products and categorized too like this:

[image]

And I based my checkboxes from here: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/fancy-bootstrap-checkboxes

I count the number of products checked in between the tabs like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  jQuery(".select-product").change(function() {

    jQuery(".counter").text(jQuery("[type='checkbox']:checked").length);

  });

});
```

But the glyphicon check icons doesn't appear on the second and third tabs for some reason. But when I click the products on the second and third, it increases the counter and also when I view it on the first tab, it is checked.

I just need the products to also be visibly checked on the second and third tabs and not only on the first one so it's not confusing for the user.

Ideas, anyone?

**Edit:** I fetch the list of products from CMS so it's dynamic. I now understand that the duplication of IDs is causing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before we try and resolve this issues, we should break it down and see what the *actual* problem is.

**First**, let's check *if we remove the `content` from tab `1b` is the issue still present?*

Nope, if we remove the checkboxes from the first tab, the checkboxes function normally on the second and third.

**[Fiddle #1](https://jsfiddle.net/pb23Ljd8/6/)**

---

What if we change the `id` of the checkboxes (remember [ids should be unique](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp)).

Notice how `Book #1` now works if we change the first checkbox's `id` to `1a`.

**[Fiddle #2](https://jsfiddle.net/pb23Ljd8/7/)**

---

So now we *"know"* the issue is likely due to the fact that we are using checkboxes with the same `id` value ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32077345/javascript-check-all-checkboxes-with-same-id)). The *"issue"* is *now*:

#### How do we check multiple checkboxes if one is checked

*(or something like that)*

Here's what I would do:

- assign all *"like"* checkboxes the same `class` *(ex. `Book #1` checkboxes will have class `b1`)*
- use jQuery/javascript to make sure all that all *"like"* checkboxes, *check* and *uncheck* in unison

**[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/b9zd2bsw/2/)**

---

**EDIT**

Dynamic values for the classes can be achieved by putting the IDs as classes so the similar products would match. These can be passed to JS like this assuming that `$products_id_array` is a PHP array that contains all the classes needed.

```
var productIDs = <?php echo json_encode($products_id_array) ?>;
```

and then creating the snippet of jQuery code on the fiddle like this

```
productIDs.forEach(function(val, key) {
    jQuery('.' + val).on('change', function(){
        jQuery('.' + val).prop('checked',this.checked);
    });
})
```

Comment: Exactly, **Invalid HTML** to start with.

Comment: Right, I see.. Thank you for this, I didn't even notice it was duplicating the IDs. But this raises another issue because these products are dynamic and called from CMS so I couldn't individually make `$('.b1').prop('checked',this.checked);` for everything. I'll edit the question for this note.

Comment: @Suika regardless of how the `id`s are set, it's *invalid* and causing issue; if it were me I would change the way you dynamically generate `id`s for the various `checkboxes` or restructure the way you display elements in your tab interface, which would make this a more complex and *different* issue

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pb23Ljd8/10/) JS, This will work

```
 jQuery(".select-product").change(function() {
      var checkValue = jQuery(this).prop('checked');
      $('.select-product#' + jQuery(this)[0].id).each(function() {
          if (checkValue == true) {
              jQuery(this).prop('checked', true)
          } else {
              jQuery(this).prop('checked', false);
          }
      });
      var uniqueId = [];
      jQuery("[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
          uniqueId.push(jQuery(this)[0].id);
      });


      Array.prototype.getUnique = function() {
          var u = {},
              a = [];
          for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i) {
              if (u.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) {
                  continue;
              }
              a.push(this[i]);
              u[this[i]] = 1;
          }
          return a;
      }
      jQuery(".counter").text(uniqueId.getUnique().length);          
  });
```

Comment: Is the JS the only changed here from the fiddle? I tried applying it to my codes and it didn't change anything. Counter is updating but the checkboxes on the other tabs still don't show.

Comment: @Suika yes only js change ,you can check out in fiddle